# Redimensionar un DataFrame en pandas con prefijos

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un DataFrame que quiero que tenga keys 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' que se genera automaticamente al leer una tabla de un pdf con la librería tabula-py. Por el formato de la tabla el DataFrame se guarda con las keys 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'A.1' 'B.1' 'C.1' 'D.1' 'A.2' 'B.2' 'C.2' 'D.2', como puedo juntar el dataFrame en uno con las 4 keys que quiero, que contenga la información de las 12 que salen.

Comment: separa las columnas y luego concatenas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Al final he utilizado el método de pandas pd.wide_to_long() y antes he tenido que añadir un prefijo .0 a las columnas que no tenían prefijo.